# AVL TREE DELETION: calculating new height of the replacing node

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm trying to implement an avl tree. I have a height field in each node which represents the max distance to null. When I delete a node, I replace it with its successor. But I have a problem determining what the height of of the new node will be (in place of the deleted node). How can I determine its height?

Comment: show us what you already have and what you tried until now so we can provide help.

Comment: Hey can you give an example tree along with the values you store. It is not clear to me what `represents the max distance to null`. This is implementation dependent.

Comment: for example 1,2,3
2 is the root with a height of 2
1,3 are its descendants with a height of 1.
when I delete 2, 3 its successor should be placed instead, with a height of 2. Giving the result: root is 3 with height of 2, 1 it's its child on the left with a height of 1. thanks